# Can an ISIN have a mixed issuance?

Tags: market-data

In principle, an ISIN is issued by one entity (which can, of course, issue multiple ISINs).

However, can an ISIN have a mixed issuance?

Comment: What do you mean by mixed issuance? For example, a corporation issues a bond and gets an ISIN assigned to the bond; then the corporation merges or changes name; then the new corpoation taps the bond issue (sells more of the same bond with the same ISIN)?

Comment: If you mean that multiple parties can collaborate and issue one product with one ISIN: yes. If you mean that one product has multiple ISIN's then no: because how would you trade this product? If the product has multiple instruments in it with it's own ISIN, then you have a package.